# visio 2010: extract shapes names

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

I was given a visio drawing of some college's architecture and want to find the name of the shapes he used there in order to save myself the trouble of locating his drawing and copying his shapes.

i also don't want to make a stencil just for these shapes, just get their names.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility that will do this for you:

http://www.sandrila.co.uk/visio-utilities/

menu SuperUtis -> Document -> Shapes in Document Report